# Counting Total Number of Occurrences of Each Type in a Table Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table and it looks like this:

[image]

When I save this data as a CSV file and upload it to my Rails application, my app takes this data and stores it in a database table called "fruitnames." It then redirects back to the homepage where it shows the data in a table.

What I'm trying to do is list the number of each type of fruit above the table. So for example, an output in the view might be:

- apple: 3
- orange: 1
- blueberry: 1
- pineapple: 1

And then if a user uploads another CSV that contains a different fruit like an avocado, then the list above should be updated.

I'm really not sure how to go about this. I tried to start off writing a query, but I'm not sure if it's right:

```
SELECT ClassName, COUNT(*) 
FROM fruitnames
GROUP BY ClassName
```

The above query obviously won't work in Rails (I'd need to write something like fruitnames.distinct.count('ClassName') or something like that). So my question is, **how can I count the number of occurrences of each ClassName and have the count show up in my view?**

My guess would involve creating a def in my controller and then inside of it, allocating a variable to the query and then embedding that variable in my erb file with a loop of some kind.

**FURTHER CLARIFICATION:**
When I type "rails c" into my command line, it opens up the IRB. If I type "fruitnames.distinct.count('ClassName')," it will find the number of distinct values in ClassName which is 4 in this case. For starters, how can I get this number to show up in my view?

Comment: Why are you not sure? Is there any problem with that query?

Comment: @CL. Well, for starters, how would that query be represented in Rails? For example, the following would print out the number of distinct values: fruitnames.distinct.count('ClassName'). So how would I write the above query into this form?